# Implement reCAPTCHA v3 on multiple forms in a page

Tags: javascript, recaptcha

I have a problem.
How to have to implement reCAPTCHA v3 on all the forms in a page?

Help please. Thanks!

Comment: `How to have a few` Can you please explain more on this?

Comment: Of course!
There are several forms on one page.
Each of them needs to be protected.

Comment: I have edited your question, please include what have you tried so far.... thats how this site works, solutions on top of ur existing code.

Comment: Welcome to SO ;) Please read this article on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This would include a proper description of what you are trying to achieve, your code (or the relevant snippets) as well as your efforts showing what you have tried so far and possible error messages.

Answer (score 0):

Thank!
I solved my problem.
It was necessary to add a call the function

```
grecaptcha.execute('fjhdjfhfjhdjfhdjhfdhfhdfbeywtwyteweiu', {action: 'homepage'})
        .then(function(token) {
            console.log(token);
            document.getElementById('response-testdrive').value = token;
        });
```

how many times you need.
And assign value in required input

```
<input type="text" name="response-testdrive" id="response-testdrive">
```